# About .net async/await Task.FromExcetpion

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, task

which should be correct? line 1 or line 2
or both correct?
Give some advice,thx

```
public static Task<int> TestAsync(int i)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
    
              // 1. throw new Exception();
               2.return Task.FromException<int>(new Exception());
            }
            else
            {
                return TTTAsync();
            }
        }

 public static Task<int> TTTAsync()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(1);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to use `async` and `await`:

```
public static async Task<int> TestAsync(int i)
{
  if (i > 0)
  {
    throw new Exception();
  }
  else
  {
    return await TTTAsync();
  }
}
```

Removing `async`/`await` in methods with any kind of logic [can be dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), as I describe on my blog.

But, if you are absolutely sure you don't want to use `async` for some reason, then you should use `Task.FromResult`:

```
public static Task<int> TestAsync(int i)
{
  if (i > 0)
  {
    return Task.FromException<int>(new Exception());
  }
  else
  {
    return TTTAsync();
  }
}
```